# How do I attach the excel file to the email?

Tags: php, laravel, email-attachments, maatwebsite-excel

I think Im close, I just need to pass the $excelFile in Mail but it keeps saying its undefined, yet when I pass $truckstop_post it goes through but that data is not formatted correctly bc it didnt go through the Excel::create yet.  How do I get the result of \Excel::create into the Mail::send??

```
public function truckstopPost()
{   
    $type = 'csv';



    $truckstop_post = Loadlist::select('pick_city', 'pick_state', 'delivery_city', 'delivery_state', 'trailer_type', 'pick_date', 'load_type', 'length', 'width', 'height', 'weight', 'offer_money', 'special_instructions', 'company_contact', 'contact_phone')->where('urgency', 'OPEN')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    $excelFile = \Excel::create('itransys', function($excel) use ($truckstop_post) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($truckstop_post)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($truckstop_post);

        });


       $info = Load::find(8500);

       $info = ['info'=>$info];


       Mail::send(['html'=>'email.invoice_email_body'], $info, function($message) use ($info, $excelFile){

        $message->to('mike@gmail.com')->subject('subject');

        $message->from('mike@gmail.com', \Auth::user()->name);

        $message->attachData($excelFile, 'Invoice.csv');

        });


        });

    return back()->with('status', 'You Posted Truckstop!');

}
```

This is what the results look like if I pass $truckstop_post into attachData() but of course thats not a nicely formatted csv file

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Generate the excel? Attach it to email?

Comment: How to attach it to the email, whats goes in  $message->attachData(???, 'Invoice.csv');   Then what happens to ->download($type);?

Comment: So remove everything that is not related to the attachment of the file from the question. Say that you have the file X and you would like to attache it.

Comment: He doesnt have file X. He's just creating the file on the fly and returning on the route. That's his problem. He's not storing the file

Comment: @Paras So the question should be "how do I store the data from the route as a file?" This is why I asked what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Please post your error message and stack trace

Comment: ErrorException in MaatwebsiteDemoController.php line 99:
Undefined variable: excelFile
in MaatwebsiteDemoController.php line 99
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined variable: excelFile', '/home/vagrant/Code/itransportsystems/app/Http/Controllers/MaatwebsiteDemoController.php', '99', array('excel' => object(LaravelExcelWriter), 'truckstop_post' => object(Collection), 'info' => array('info' => object(Load)))) in MaatwebsiteDemoController.php line 99
at MaatwebsiteDemoController->App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(object(LaravelExcelWriter))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like so

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel as BaseExcel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

...

$filename = "my_file.csv";

$attachment = Excel::raw(
    new PurchaseOrderLinesExport($this->data), 
    BaseExcel::CSV
);
$subject = "Purchase Order"

return $this->from($this->employee->email)
            ->subject("Purchase Order)
            ->view('emails.view')
            ->attachData($attachment, $filename);
```

`Excel::raw()` method creates/writes a temporary file and then gets its contents and delete after deleting that file.

**Second Solution would be like this if you're using laravel:**

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.report')
        ->attach(
            Excel::download(
                new AuditReport($this->audit), 
                'report.xlsx'
            )->getFile(), ['as' => 'report.xlsx']
        );
}
```

`Excel::download()` returns a `BinaryFileResponse` that's why it doesn't work directly, but you can grab the file.

Comment: Thanks, `Excel::raw(new ExcelExport($this->data), \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);` combined with `attachData` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Laravel 9, it's possible to use the [`attachments()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#raw-data-attachments) method in the Mailable class:

```php
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel as BaseExcel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

public function attachments(): array
{
    return [
        Attachment::fromData(fn () => Excel::raw(new UsersExport(), BaseExcel::XLSX), 'report.xlsx'),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function post()
{   
    $type = 'csv';

    $create_excel = List::select('pick_city', 'pick_state', 'delivery_city', 'delivery_state')->where('urgency', 'OPEN')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->toArray();

    $excelFile = \Excel::create('itrans', function($excel) use ($create_excel) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($create_excel)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($create_excel);


        });

    })->download($type);

    Mail::send(['html'=>'email.email_body'] function($message) {

     $message->to('example@gmail.com')

    ->subject('Email Subject Line');

    $message->from('daniel@twbb.com', 'Daniel');

    $message->attachData($excelFile, 'Invoice.csv');

});

    return $excelFile;

}
```

Comment: Post the output of dd($create_excel)

Comment: can you dd($create_excel) after the line where it is initialized and before the \Excel::create is called?